# When to specify dependencies in Makefiles explicitly?

Tags: makefile, fortran, dependencies, fortran90

## Introduction

Many programs call a tree of subroutines, functions, and/or elements from modules. Suppose all such elements are contained in separate files, and some call others. I'm wondering about dependencies between these elements/files during the compilation process in the context of Makefiles. I'll use Fortran for example, but this question is at least *somewhat* language-agnostic.

## Example

Suppose the program has the following dependencies:

- `MyProgram` calls `subroutineA` and `subroutineB`.
- `subroutineA` calls `subroutineC`.
- `subroutineB` calls `functionD` and uses the parameter `pi` defined in module `constants`..
- `subroutineC` uses the parameter `pi` defined in module `constants`.
- `functionD` calls nothing.

(The `constants` module could be the one given [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_modules.htm).) Each program, subroutine, function or module is defined in a file with a matching name.

The corresponding Makefile could be written in at least three ways, as illustrated below, and I'm wondering which is best. In the example Makefiles, I'm assuming the usual Makefile variables have been set earlier in the Makefile:

- `F90` is set to the appropriate Fortran compiler (e.g. `FC=ifort`)
- `FFLAGS` is the set of compiler flags (e.g. `FFLAGS=-O2`)

#### Trivial Makefile

Everything gets compiled at once:

```
MyProgram: constants.f90 myprogram.f90 subroutineA.f90 subroutineB.f90 subroutineC.f90 functionD.f90 
    $(FC) $^ $(FFLAGS) -o $@
```

#### More "Standard" Makefile

Precompiles the subroutines and functions via a Makefile pattern rule but precompiles the module separately. At the end, it compiles/links them all together at the end.

```
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $^ -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@

%.o %.mod: %.f90
    $(FC) $^ -c $(FFLAGS)

MyProgram: constants.o constants.mod myprogram.o subroutineA.o subroutineB.o functionC.o 
    $(FC) $(filter %.o,$^) $(FFLAGS) -o $@
```

#### Explicit Makefile

Expresses each dependency explicitly. This gives `make` has a complete, [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of dependencies:

```
MyProgram: constants.o myprogram.o subroutineA.o subroutineB.o subroutineC.o functionD.o constants.mod
    $(FC) $(filter %.o,$^ ) -o $@

myprogram.o: myprogram.f90 subroutineA.o subroutineB.o
    $(FC) -c $< -o $@

subroutineA.o: subroutineA.f90 subroutineC.o
    $(FC) -c $< -o $@

subroutineB.o: subroutineB.f90 functionD.o constants.o constants.mod
    $(FC) -c $< -o $@

subroutineC.o: subroutineC.f90 constants.o constants.mod
    $(FC) -c $< -o $@

functionD.o: functionD.f90
    $(FC) -c $< -o $@

constants.o constants.mod: constants.f90
    $(FC) -c $<
```

## My Question

For my question, let's assume the Makefile has enough files and/or is used by enough different developers to warrant using a Makefile over manual compilation, but not so many files that writing out dependencies explicitly is unreasonable or impossible.

**Is it important, good practice, or necessary to write out explicit dependencies for these things in a Makefile? Under what circumstances might it be best to use the "Explicit Makefile" approach as opposed to the "More Standard Makefile"?**

Also, does the answer to that question depend on whether or not modules are involved?

Comment: Or have the compiler generate the dependency list.

Comment: Most makefiles have both implicit and explicit rules.